# Android Http Request: I don't understand the following code:

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest

So I'm doing this Udacity Android App Developer course and the code isn't explained well. So this is about a Http Request. What does the scanner do here? What is the \A delimiter? why is it returning the scanner.next()? what is the disconnect() method?

```
 public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs for Scanner? Re: disconnect--based on the name what's your guess? It also has docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Scanner is the java class which is used for evaluating the strings (texts),where useDelimiter() function used to delimiting pattern, where how words are splitting from each other, for more info please check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-usedelimiter-method-in-java-with-examples/), where hasNext() returning you splitted string, checkout this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-hasnext-method), and when you get response successfully from server 
  'urlConnection.disconnect()' method will close your connection to server.

Comment: and what is the "\\A"? the delimiter is letter A?

Comment: Delimiter letter will be "\\A"

Comment: so basically this code is splitting the input URLs and the sending a http request right?

Comment: No, its splitting the server response, this is only function and URL is GET not POST, for that you have to learn first GET and POST request